# Calculation of Fibonacci numbers

Tags: matlab, fibonacci

As an exercise for a MATLAB course, I have to calculate the first 100 [Fibonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) using for loops in MATLAB. Here is my code:

```
for N=[0:1]
    N=N
end

for N=[2:1:100]
    N= N-1+N-2
end
```

The result however is wrong: The output is `0,1,1,3,...` instead of `0,1,1,2,3,...` - i.e. the `2` is missing.
Where is the mistake in my code?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I reworded the question and applied code highlighting, to make the question (imo) more understandable. If you don't agree with the edit, feel free to undo the edit by clicking on "edited ... ago" and then clicking "rollback".

Answer (score 2):

you are rewriting `N` instead of building a vector of numbers `N`. don't mix the dummy loop variable with the variable you iterate on.

```
N=[0 1];
for x=3:100
    N(x)=N(x-2)+N(x-1);
end
```